# Using ffmpeg to encode a raw video to H.264 format

Tags: ubuntu, video, ffmpeg, h.264

On a Ubuntu 10.04, I am trying to encode a raw video (YUV format) to a H.264 encoded video using below ffmpeg commands:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.h264
```

but I get an error saying

> Unsupported codec for output stream #0.0

Then when I try this option:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -formats h264 output.h264
```

it still does not encode.

Now I understood that ffmpeg uses libx264 for encoding to H.264 format. Now I have the package x264 - fast H.264 encoder installed on this Ubuntu.

My questions:

1. Is there any relation between this libx264 which ffmpeg needs and x264 program?
2. How do I install libx264 and make ffmpeg use this to allow me to encode a video to H.264 format?

Comment: What about your previous question, wasn't that solved? [ffmpeg usage to encode a video to H264 codec format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678695/ffmpeg-usage-to-encode-a-video-to-h264-codec-format)

Comment: @slhck - Thanks but, When I used:- ffmpeg -s 352x240 -i 352x240_420.yuv  -vcodec libx264 out.mp4. It gave error - "Unknown encoder 'libx264'". Any further pointers. Is libx264 same as x264 library or something other.

Comment: Regarding compiling ffmpeg and x264 on Linux, see here: http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all, those commands you use look syntactically incorrect. In order to have ffmpeg use x264, you need to supply the `-c:v libx264` argument.

Now, if you have a raw YUV file, you need to tell ffmpeg which pixel format, which size, etc. is used:

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -s:v 1920x1080 -r 25 -i input.yuv \
-c:v libx264 output.mp4
```

Change these according to your YUV file's specifications. Have a look at `ffmpeg -pix_fmts` for a list of supported pixel formats. [fourcc.org](http://fourcc.org/) is also a good resource on that.

If you just want the raw H.264 bitstream in a `.264` file:

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -s:v 1920x1080 -r 25 -i input.yuv \
-c:v libx264 -f rawvideo output.264
```

Comment: Why do you have to tell ffmpeg size, pix and frame rate? Why can't it detect it normaly like when using a non-raw video...

Comment: @RicardoBohner Because raw video, like the name says, is just a bunch of video pixels (simply speaking). In order to know how many pixels a frame is, and how fast to play each frame, you have to tell ffmpeg these metadata. Normally, that is all stored in a container, which, for raw video, is not present.

Comment: thank you very much for the expanation

Answer (score 0):

> ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -s:v 1920x1080 -r 23.976 -i raw_i420_1920_1080  -vcodec libx264  -f rawvideo output.264

`-vcodec` tells it which codec to use. `man ffmpeg` will help you learn more.